# FusionPBX installation 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: linux, centos, freeswitch, pbx, fusionpbx

I am trying to install FusionPBX on Centos 7 operating system using this below link.

https://www.fusionpbx.com/download.php

After successful installation, I am getting an error

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.12.2

[FusionPBX Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWC1S.png)

Please, can anyone help me to fix the FusionPBX error.

Answer (score 0):

Well my previous post with and example from the error logs was deleted.

I did dig into this further and found a fix. The issue is caused by a difference between the Nginx and php-fpm users. To fix the issue, update `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
;listen.owner = nobody
listen.owner = freeswitch
;listen.group = nobody
listen.group = daemon
```

For further details: https://www.bytesolutions.com/fusionpbx-error-502-bad-gateway/